# Radon-Nikodym Derivative of a Mixed Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure, density-function, radon-nikodym

When we have a continuous distribution $F_X(x)$, we can take the Radon-Nikodym derivative (RND) of the probability measure with respect to Lebesgue measure to get the density $f_X(x)$.

When we have a discrete distribution, we can take the RND with respect to the counting measure to get the mass function (so "density" in measure theoretic probability).

When we have a mixed distribution, say 50% standard normal and 50% 0s (so a jump discontinuity in the CDF at 0, see the drawing), what would be the measure to use that is some kind of hybrid of Lebesgue and counting measure?

[image]

(Starts out looking normal, jumps up at 0, then gets back to looking normal.)

Comment: there is no standard measure in such case. The approach is to write the distribution as a convex sum of distributions: one absolutely continuous, other discrete, and the other continuous and singular. Because the distribution is increasing then it is differentiable a.e. (respect to the Lebesgue measure) and it derivative is the density of it absolutely continuous part

Comment: @Masacroso That seems to lose the discrete part of the distribution.

Comment: yes, but the discrete part is easy to get: it is just the collection of jumps of the distribution

Comment: @Masacroso That makes it sound like we're not really unifying probability theory via measure theory.

Comment: Your question makes no sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This is all phrased in terms of measures and not in terms of distributions, since in the comments you said you want a measure-theoretic approach.)

I think what you want to do is to break up some probability measure into parts which are easier to understand.

One of the theorems which accomplishes this is *Lebesgue decomposition theorem*:

> Let $\mu, \nu$ be $\sigma$-finite measures defined on the same measurable space. Then there exists with respect to $\mu$ both an absolutely continuous measure $\nu_{\text{as}}$ and a singular measure $\nu_{\text{s}}$ such that
> $$ \nu = \nu_{\text{ac}} + \nu_{\text{s}}.$$

Here a singular measure $\lambda$ with respect to $\mu$ is a measure such that there exists a set $X$ with measure zero with respect to $\mu$ such that $\lambda(X^c)=0$. In other words, we divide the measure space into a part which we measure with $\lambda$, and another part which we measure with $\mu$.

This theorem can be refined even more to obtain $$\nu = \nu_{\text{ac}} + \nu_{\text{pp}}  +  \nu_{\text{s}},$$ where $\nu_{\text{ac}}$ is again absolutely continous with respect to $\mu$, $\nu_{pp}$ is a discrete measure (i.e. a sum $\sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}} z_j \delta_{x_j}$, with the $(x_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ being points in the measure space and $(z_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{{R_0^{+}}^{N}}$), and $\nu_{s}$ is again singular with respect to $\mu$.

Now we can use this to get a sort of "generalised Radon-Nikodým-derivative" (or a "generalised density" if you will), only that it consists out of multiple parts which are relative to several measures:

> Let $\mu$ be your probability measure and $\lambda$ the Lebesgue-measure. Then we can write
> $$ \mu(A) = \int_A \frac{d\mu_{ac}}{d\lambda} d\lambda + \sum_{x \in \sigma(\mu_{pp})} \int_A  \frac{d\mu_{pp}}{d\delta_{x}} d\delta_x + \mu_s(A),  $$
> for any measurable $A$.

Here $\sigma(\nu_{\text{pp}})$ denotes the support of $\nu_{\text{pp}},$ that is all points in the measure space on which the measure isn't zero (which is at most countable since it is discrete).

This essentially is what Masacroso has commented in more measure-theoretic terms.

In general you won't be able to get rid of the singular part $\nu_s$, but you could for example try to decompose that using the above theorem with respect to some other measure. But I think in the example you have in mind (a sort of superposition of a Lebesgue measure and a Dirac measure) $\nu_s$ should be zero.

*EDIT*: In the case of the sketch which was added to the question the measure $\mu$ looks like $$\mu(-\infty, x) = f(x),$$ where $f: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ is absolutely continuous on both $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$ with a jump discontinuity at $0$.

To decompose $\mu$ as above we note that for $a < b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 \notin [a,b]$ we have $$ \mu(a,b] = \mu(-\infty, b] - \mu(-\infty, a].  $$

To find the discrete parts we calculate the measure of the singletons $\{ x \}$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}:$
$$ \mu\{ x \} = \mu(-\infty, x] - \lim_{\varepsilon \uparrow 0} \mu(-\infty, \varepsilon] = \begin{cases}
0 & x \neq 0 \\
f(0^+) - f(0^-) & x = 0
\end{cases},$$

since we only have a discontinuity at $0$. Now for again $a < 0 < b \in \mathbb{R}$ we can write

$$ \mu(a,b] = \mu(a,0) + \mu\{0\} + \mu(0, b]. $$

Now define $\mu_{\text{ac}}(a, b] := \mu((a,b]\backslash\{0\}), $ and $\mu_{\text{pp}}(a,b] := \mu\{0\}\delta_0(a,b].$ These can be extended to full measures for arbitrary measurable sets.

> Then we have
> $$ \mu = \mu_{\text{ac}} + \mu_{\text{pp}}, $$
> with $$\frac{d\mu_{\text{ac}}}{d\lambda} = f', \ \frac{d\mu_{\text{pp}}}{d\delta_0} = \mu\{0\}.$$

Comment: I have to read this a couple of times, but I'm only considering a mixture of a decent continuous distribution and a discrete. The $\nu_s$ would be something like the Cantor distribution, right? I don't mean that. So is the gist just to take the RND with respect to Lebesgue measure where that makes sense and with respect to counting measure where that makes sense?

Comment: @Dave The Cantor measure is singular with respect to the Lebesgue measure, yes. I don't exactly know what you mean by "take the derivative where it makes sense". Do you have a specific example in mind? Finding the Lebesgue decomposition of a general measure can be hard. Most often just the existence is used to proof some properties of the measure under examination.

Comment: Example: 50% of the density is standard normal, 50% is 0. I tend to work with data that, except for a bunch of ties at 0, seem to come from continuous distributions.

Comment: @Dave I don't quite get what that means. Can you write the concrete measure down as $\mu(A) = \dots$?

Comment: I'm not coming up with how to write the mixed probability measure, though I did put a drawing in my question.

Comment: @Dave I've added a section on your drawing to my answer.

Comment: thanks for this great answer. in your section abt the generalized radon nikodym derivative, is it supposed to be $\mu$ instead of $\nu$ in the numerator of the first term, or am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnMadden Glad to help. You're right about the $\nu$, i fixed it in the answer.

Comment: @JannikPitt can you point me to an academic reference that talks about this "generalized RN derivative" by any chance?

Comment: @JohnMadden There are some references listed at the Wikipedia article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem. The theorem is called *Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem* and should be found in most good texts on measure theory.